# AWS ASG Error: Client.InternalError: Client error on launch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-kms

I created a new ASG that creates instances using an AMI that has been created and encrypted in another account (account id: 111). Any instance that creates in the ASG crashes right away with an error of `Client.InternalError: Client error on launch`. It seems that the instance has no permissions to the KMS key. I went over similar questions and checked the relevant [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/key-policy-requirements-EBS-encryption.html#configuring-key-policies), but I haven't figured out the issue.

Here is the key policy in account id 111. I gave privileges to the relevant user from account id 222, which is where i created the ASG.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "key-default-1",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Enable IAM User Permissions",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::222:role/instances_profile",
                ]
            },
            "Action": "kms:*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is the relevant grant:

```
aws kms list-grants --key-id arn:aws:kms:us-east-1:111:key/84848484 --region us-east-1
{
    "Grants": [
        {
            "KeyId": "arn:aws:kms:us-east-1:111:key/84848484",
            "Name": "stage",
            "GranteePrincipal": "arn:aws:iam::222:role/instances_profile",
            "IssuingAccount": "arn:aws:iam::111:root",
            "Operations": [
                "Decrypt",
                "Encrypt",
                "GenerateDataKey",
                "GenerateDataKeyWithoutPlaintext",
                "ReEncryptFrom",
                "ReEncryptTo",
                "CreateGrant",
                "DescribeKey"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The EC2 instance has the following policy:

```
{
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": "kms:Decrypt",
    "Resource": "arn:aws:kms:us-east-1:111:key/84848484"
}
```

Does anyone know what could be the issue?

Comment: What is the role being used by the vms?

Comment: @Paolo i've updated my question with the policy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was resolved. I had to use the service-linked role and not the service role.

I had to use: `arn:aws:iam::222:role/aws-service-role/autoscaling.amazonaws.com/AWSServiceRoleForAutoScaling` for the `GranteePrincipal` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The KMS key policy you've provided gives permissions to the root user in account 222. However, the EC2 instances created by the ASG likely aren't running with the permissions of the root user. Instead, they're probably running with the permissions of an EC2 instance profile, which is a role that's attached to the EC2 instances when they're launched.

To solve the issue, you would need to modify your KMS key policy to allow the EC2 instance profile used by the ASG in account 222 to use the KMS key. You would replace `"arn:aws:iam::222:root"` in the key policy with the ARN of the instance profile.

Here's an example of what the modified key policy might look like:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "key-default-1",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Enable IAM User Permissions",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::222:role/your-instance-profile-role",
                ]
            },
            "Action": "kms:*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Replace `"arn:aws:iam::222:role/your-instance-profile-role"` with the ARN of your instance profile. You can find this information in the IAM console in your AWS account.

Please note that the permissions in the policy above are quite broad (`"kms:*"` and `"Resource": "*"`) and may not follow the best security practices. It's generally recommended to restrict the permissions to the minimum necessary for your application to function properly.

Comment: *Many* of your recent answers appear likely to have been entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT). As a heads-up, [posting of AI-generated content is not permitted on Stack Overflow](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool for assistance on this answer, could I ask you to (1) Reply in a comment here confirming that it was AI-generated, along with what tool (e.g., ChatGPT, Bing Chat, Copilot, etc.) -- We're compiling data on AI-assisted answers and could use your help. (2) After commenting, I recommend deleting your answer.  Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly. The moderation team can use your help to identify quality issues.

Comment: I'm an AWS architecture and I know what I'm writing for

Comment: I did notice that in your profile, but the answers you are posting still seem to be coming mostly from a GPT system, which is currently not allowed.

Comment: I'm writing a reply to the questions, explaining what they're doing, with my style of writing. I think you can see my other answers from the past and see that this is how I answer them (for example answer # 64688073 )

Comment: While I understand that you have demonstrated expertise in the areas you are posting, it still appears to me (and others) that your recent answers have likely been assisted by a GPT.  And no, your earlier answers do *not* appear to be assisted by AI. 
 I'm all for [responsible use of AI](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/389675/902710) here on SO, but currently it's not allowed at all due to many users using it irresponsibly.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, and I know I can do little to nothing to prove I did it by myself. AI is so good that lots of the time there literally no difference. But I want to be honest, this is discouraging

Comment: @70ny i've just tried that, but ended up with the same error. I've updated my question with the profile role.

Comment: @Supertwister any chance you can get more info from CloudTrail logs? Cause looks like it might be also the policy atached to the EC2 instance, that needs not just the `kms:Decrypt`

Comment: @70ny i've tired using `kms:*` instead and still got the same error

Comment: No logs on cloud trail? Cause maybe we're looking in the wrong place (no KMS issue)

Comment: Issue was resolved. I had to use the service-linked role and not the service role.  I had to use: `arn:aws:iam::222:role/aws-service-role/autoscaling.amazonaws.com/AWSServiceRoleForAutoScaling` for the `GranteePrincipal` parameter. Thanks!